# For loop in flutter (dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, for-loop

hey guys I am little confused by the for loop character in flutter. I have 4 receipt and each have 2 items, I was expect the loop flow 4 times, but I found it run 8 times,

I have two local Sqllite db ReceiptDatabase & ItemsDatabase. They have 1 to many relationship. inside itemsDatabase there is receiptId column.

**What I was tried**

```
    await getReceiptsFromSqlite();
    _data = [];
    for(var rec in _receipts)  {
      print(_receipts.length); //4
      print(rec.id); //1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4
      _items =[];
      _items=await ItemsDatabase.instance.readItems(rec.id!); 
      MainData md = MainData.fromJson(LocalReceipt.mapAsNonSqlStructure(rec, _items));
      _data.add(md);
    }

  Future getReceiptsFromSqlite() async {
    _receipts = await ReceiptDatabase.instance.readAllReceipts();
  }
```

can any body explain the case, please

Comment: This code is not very self explanatory, we don't know how do you fill `_receipts`, neither how is your data. I'm gessing you are saving the items inside the `LocalReceipt` class not the actual receipt, that's why your id is the same.

Comment: @FelipeMorschel thanks for your fast response, I added additional info, can you please look it again

Comment: Thank you for explaining it better, I'm still not able to quite understand what you are doing because I dont have a deep understanding of your full system. What I suggest you do here is try using `debugPrint` or `print` (removing this later) of your `_receipts` iterable (maybe as a map of all your data inside them). And for understanding the actual functionality of `for` - `in` loops, I suggest looking at the docs here https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops, and for trying it out I suggest you use https://dartpad.dev

Comment: ok thanks, when I comment out ```_items=await ItemsDatabase.instance.readItems(rec.id!); ``` it works as expected, I don't know what is happing, any ways thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it has happened to anyone else or not but sometimes if I am running the debug apk for quite some time and making changes to it by doing a hot restart and hot reload, some of my methods start getting called multiple times and even my FirebaseAuth.userChanges listener starts getting called more than once without any changes to the Firebase User. So, to rule this possibility out, please try running the flutter clean command and try rebuilding the app.

**P.S: This would be the case only if your loop normally runs fine and does this repeating twice behavior sometimes.**